# Given the matrix, find a matrix such that

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}$
>
> $T(\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find a matrix such that:
>
> $T(\vec{v}) = \begin{bmatrix}&\\\\\end{bmatrix} $

How do I approach this question? I just need a step in the right direction. I don't understand what they want me to find?

Comment: Given a 2 by 2 matrix $A$ such that $A\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}$ and $A\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}=1\\-5\end{bmatrix}$ Let the entries of $A$ be $a,b,c,d$ respectively. Matrix multiplication allows you to calculate the entries.

Comment: Yeah, what? You're saying multiply 1,-2 with 3,10 and similarly -2,-1 wiith -1,-5??

Comment: No, that is not what I have written.The matrix $A$ that has entries $a,b$ on the first row and $c,d$ on the second is multiplied with a vector to get another vector. This you do twice. You get systems of equations in $a,b,c,d$ which are easy to solve...

Answer (score 3):

First find $T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix})$ and $T(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix})$, the transformation of standard base vectors $\in\Bbb R^2$
So$$T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix})=\frac15\left(T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix})-2T(\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix})\right)=\frac15\left(\begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\end{bmatrix}$$$$T(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix})=-\frac12\left(T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix})-T(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix})\right)=-\frac12\left(\begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-3\end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore,$$T(\vec{v}) = \begin{bmatrix}v_1-v_2\\4v_1-3v_2\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Notice that 
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=
\frac15\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{bmatrix}
-\frac25\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}=
-\frac25\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{bmatrix}
-\frac15\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then, we have
\begin{align*}
T\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\frac15T\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}-\frac25T\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\frac15\begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}-\frac25\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
T\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=-\frac25T\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}-\frac15T\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}=-\frac25\begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}-\frac15\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The matrix equation is
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} &= \mathbf{C} \\
% A
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\ c & d
\end{array} \right]
% B
\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
  1 & -2 \\ -2 & 1
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
% C
\left[ \begin{array}{cr}
  3 & -1 \\ 10 & -5
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The solution is
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{C} \mathbf{B}^{-1} \\[2pt]
% A
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\ c & d
\end{array} \right]
&=
% C
\left[ \begin{array}{cr}
  3 & -1 \\ 10 & -5
\end{array} \right]
% B inc
\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)
\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
  1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1
\end{array} \right] \\[4pt]
%
&= 
\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
 -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{5}{3} \\ 0 & -5
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$